# Application doesn't start

Tags: c#

I am having a rather strange problem, I deployed 2 .NET applications on my machine. Both run on v2.0.

Now, while one of it works smoothly, the other one doesn't even start! Moreover, it doesn't throw any error, I couldn't see any error listings in the Event Viewer.

Becoming hard to debug. On every other machine, both the exe's work perfectly fine!

Any known issues?

EDIT:
I caught an Unhandled Exception and the exception is this;

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Class not registered(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
>      at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithLicense(String license, Guid clsid)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
>      at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
>      at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
>      at BrowsingFiles.Form1.InitializeComponent()
>      at BrowsingFiles.Form1..ctor()
>      at BrowsingFiles.Program.Main(String[] args)

Thanks

Comment: Right, I am using a AxShowkwave Flash object which is a COM. Problem is that on any other machine it registers properly. It's only on few machine that it creates error! How do I go about registering COM then?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more solution apart from the one given by [Mitch Wheat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16076/mitch-wheat/)

Copy the DLL, in the System32 file at it's proper location and then using command prompt register the dll with the system using
regsvr32 *location-of-the-dll*

Answer (score 3):

You are calling a COM component that is not registered on that machine.

Ideally, your deployment project would register any COM dependencies: [How To Register COM Objects in Visual Studio .NET: Steps to Register a COM Module in a Visual Studio .Net Deployment Project](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307367)

Comment: Hi, this sounds neat, but I am building a custom installer! Any help with that respect would really work for me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can go to project -> add reference to add your com component.  Make sure you have the com component loaded on this system.  You can go and view the references on your previous machine and see where the references are located and modify this new machine accordingly.